# why can't I access a key of an object with input values

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am trying to write a program in which when user choses an option of select input the program saves it in a variable and then uses that variable to find the chosen option's name in an object and then show the value of that key.
but it returns undefined every time, why does this happen and how can I fix it.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <select id="select">
        <option value="cat">cat</option>
        <option value="lion">lion</option>
        <option value="tiger">tiger</option>
    </select>
    <script src="Untitled-1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let inp = document.querySelector("#select")

let array = [
    {
        cat: 2,
        lion: 4,
        tiger: 6,
    },

    {
        camel: 2,
        lizard: 4,
        dog: 6,
    },

]
let value = inp.value
let obj = array[0]
function func() {
    console.log(obj.value)
}

inp.addEventListener("change", func)
```

Comment: I think this was closed a little early, as there's more guidance we can offer you because there's some fundamental issues besides accessing the object by property name. That said, to fix your problem, put this line of code inside `func()`: `console.log(array[0][inp.options[inp.selectedIndex].textContent.trim()])`

Comment: ask yourself ... does `array[0]` have a property called `value` - also note, `let value = inp.value` means that `value` will never change regardless of what the value of `inp.value` is